Surjective homomorphism of semirings is an order isomorphism?
I am trying to prove the following lemma (originally Prop. A.2) which I found from the paper "Containment of conjunctive queries on annotated relations" by Todd J. Green. Note that although the paper concerns database queries with semiring annotations, this lemma is purely about semirings, which is why I am asking here.
Definition
Let $K=(0,1,+,\times)$ be a semiring. The natural order on $K$ is the preorder defined by $a\leq b$ iff $\exists c\in K. a + c = b$.
We say $K$ is naturally-ordered if its natural order is a partial order, i.e. it is also antisymmetric.
The following is the lemma in interest:
Lemma
Let $K_1, K_2$ be naturally-ordered commutative semirings. If $h : K_1 \to K_2$ is a surjective semiring homomorphism, then for all $a,b\in K_1$, $a\leq b$ iff $h(a) \leq h(b)$.
Now, I managed to prove the forward direction quite easily, and it did not require surjectivity. For the backwards direction however, I failed to see why it is true, especially in where to use the being-naturally-ordered assumption and the commutativity of multiplication. Assuming that $h(a)\leq h(b)$, the furthest I got was proving the existence of a $c$ such that $h(a+c) = h(a) + h(c)= h(b)$ using surjectivity, but how do you use this to prove that $a + c = b$? Or is that the wrong approach? Thanks.

The lemma is clearly wrong, take $K_2=0$. Are you sure that you have added the whole context?

@MartinBrandenburg: quite. Or you could take $K_1 = \Bbb{N}\times\Bbb{N}$ and $K_2 = \Bbb{N}$ (under addition) and $h((i, j)) = i$.

@MartinBrandenburg I just checked and I am sure this is the statement from the paper. You have a good point about the trivial semiring.

I found the paper and you have indeed quoted it correctly. It looks like you need to be careful when applying any of the results in the paper that depend on this.

@RobArthan Luckily I am formalizing the paper in Lean, so anything wrong would (most definitely) not go through : )

Excellent! I am a very enthusiastic proponent of mechanized theorem-proving. I look forward with great interest to learn what you are able to glean from your formalization. All best wishes!

Perhaps, the lemma was meant to say "injective" instead of "surjective". If so, then $h(a+c)=h(b)$ and injectivity of $h$ would immediately imply $a+c=b$.

The lemma is wrong, as can be seen by taking $K_2=0$. There are lots of other counterexamples. For the claim to hold it is sufficient though that $h$ is an isomorphism.
